# Process a file containing a collection of JSON strings

Tags: json, file, perl, pipe

(Title edited. The original title: "*json content: print out parts of it as is, pipe parts of it to get human readable timestamps, output from the same command*")

---

I have a json alike content in a file:

```
{
  "newState": "runnable",
  "setAt": 1587421159359
}
{
  "newState": "running",
  "setAt": 1587421282891
}
{
  "newState": "debug_hold",
  "setAt": 1587422014895
}
{
  "newState": "terminating",
  "setAt": 1587424788577
}
{
  "newState": "failed",
  "setAt": 1587424796544
}
```

I can extract the 'newState' by `cat timestamps.json | jq -r '.newState'`:

```
runnable
running
debug_hold
terminating
failed
```

I can extract the epoch timestamps and format it into a human readable form by `cat timestamps.json | jq -r '.setAt'  | rev | cut -c 4- | rev | perl -pe 's/(\d+)/localtime($1)/e'`:

```
Mon Apr 20 18:19:19 2020
Mon Apr 20 18:21:22 2020
Mon Apr 20 18:33:34 2020
Mon Apr 20 19:19:48 2020
Mon Apr 20 19:19:56 2020
```

How can I combine the two outputs so the result becomes

```
runnable Mon Apr 20 18:19:19 2020
running Mon Apr 20 18:21:22 2020
debug_hold Mon Apr 20 18:33:34 2020
terminating Mon Apr 20 19:19:48 2020
failed Mon Apr 20 19:19:56 2020
```

I think I can do some bash for loop and array input but was wondering if jq has something that can pipe a portion of the content (e.g. epoch time in this case) out, process it, then feed the value back into the jq parse output.

Comment: Useless use of `cat`. Replace `cat timestamps.json |` with `<timestamps.json`

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking something like this.

```sh
cat timestamps.json | jq -r '[.newState, .setAt] | join(" ")'
```

Answer (score 2):

With input being a collection of (unrelated) valid JSON strings you can read in `{}` chunks.

Set the [input record separator (`$/`)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles) to `}` and then the `<>` operator each time reads up to `}`

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use JSON qw(decode_json);

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 file\n";  #/

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

local $/ = '}';  # presumably all this code is in some local scope

while (my $record = <$fh>) { 
    next if not $record =~ /\S/; 

    my $json = decode_json($record); 

    say $json->{newState}, ' ', scalar localtime $json->{setAt}/1000; 
}
```

Comments

- This relies on the shown format of the input, in particular that it has no nested objects. If there are nested `{...}` then slurp the whole file and extract JSON strings using `Text::Balanced` or equivalent (or, of course, use another approach)
- I'd actually recommend to use `Cpanel::JSON::XS`
- When global variables like `$/` need be changed that is best done in the smallest scope needed and with [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html).  Here it doesn't matter but I presume this to be a part of a larger program
- There may be empty strings and, in particular, newlines left over when reading this way thus the check of whether the record contains any non-whitespace
- The timestamps in your input are off by a factor of thousand from seconds-since-epoch, I guess because they carry milliseconds as well. I just divide by 1000 for simplicity
- Note that the shown desired timestamps may become a problem if daylight saving time gets involved, and if that is the case you want to extract and include the time zone as well

---

The simplest (and flexible) way to get timezone from the epoch is by using `POSIX::strftime`. It takes the list from `localtime` and returns a string generated according to the given format.

The `%z` specifier produces the timezone as the UTC offset, while `%Z` produces the (notorious and unportable) short name.  See your system's `strftime` manpage  for details. Example

```
 use POSIX qw(strftime);
 say strftime "%z %Z", localtime;  #--> -0700 PDT
```

(thanks to ikegami's answer which proded me to add the timezone discussion)

Answer (score 1):

Using the *incremental parsing* feature of JSON parsers, one can safely parse sequences of JSON documents such as the one you have with very little code. This means there's no point in hacking together a JSON parser using regex matches.

```perl
use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );

my $decoder = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new();
while (<>) {
   $decoder->incr_parse($_);
   while ( my $rec = $decoder->incr_parse() ) {
      say sprintf "%-11s %s",
         $rec->{newState},
         format_ts($rec->{setAt});
   }
}
```

Complete program:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use utf8;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use Cpanel::JSON::XS qw( );
use POSIX            qw( strftime );

sub format_ts {
   my ($ts) = @_;
   my $ms = $ts % 1000;
   my $epoch = ( $ts - $ms ) / 1000;
   my @lt = localtime($epoch);
   return sprintf("%s.%03d %s",
      strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S", @lt),
      $ms,
      strftime("%Y %z", @lt),
   );
}

my $decoder = Cpanel::JSON::XS->new();
while (<>) {
   $decoder->incr_parse($_);
   while ( my $rec = $decoder->incr_parse() ) {
      say sprintf "%-11s %s",
         $rec->{newState},
         format_ts($rec->{setAt});
   }
}
```

Output:

```
runnable    Mon Apr 20 18:19:19.359 2020 -0400
running     Mon Apr 20 18:21:22.891 2020 -0400
debug_hold  Mon Apr 20 18:33:34.895 2020 -0400
terminating Mon Apr 20 19:19:48.577 2020 -0400
failed      Mon Apr 20 19:19:56.544 2020 -0400
```

Note that I added time zone information because the timestamps would be ambiguous without it (because of overlaps when switching from daylight-saving time to standard time). I also showed how you can keep the milliseconds if you so desire.

Answer (score -2):

A small perl script can process such data with ease

> USAGE: script_name.pl timestamps.json

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my($state,$time);

while(<>) {
    chomp;
    $state = $1 if /"newState": "(.*)"/;
    $time  = $1 if /"setAt": (\d+)/;
    printf "%-12s %s\n", $state, "".localtime($time/1000) if /}/;
}
```

Alternative version

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do { local $/; <> };
my %state = $data =~ /"newState": "(.*?)".*?"setAt": (\d+)/sg;

while(my($s,$t) = each %state) {
    printf "%-12s %s\n", $s, "".localtime($t/1000);
}
```

Input file **timestamps.json**

```
{
  "newState": "runnable",
  "setAt": 1587421159359
}
{
  "newState": "running",
  "setAt": 1587421282891
}
{
  "newState": "debug_hold",
  "setAt": 1587422014895
}
{
  "newState": "terminating",
  "setAt": 1587424788577
}
{
  "newState": "failed",
  "setAt": 1587424796544
}
```

Output

```
runnable     Mon Apr 20 15:19:19 2020
running      Mon Apr 20 15:21:22 2020
debug_hold   Mon Apr 20 15:33:34 2020
terminating  Mon Apr 20 16:19:48 2020
failed       Mon Apr 20 16:19:56 2020
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I made a mistake in my original json content. The timestamps were supposed to be epoch time. I have corrected it.

Comment: @MrJanitor -- code was updated to work with corrected input data